# Creating new variables in /etc/apache2/envvars?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

On Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10, I thought I'd get clever and add

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

to `/etc/apache2/envvars` so I could DRY up my Apache configs.  But it doesn't seem to be accessible from httpd.conf.  Digging further, I started using `ErrorLog` as a test, and now I'm baffled.  Given the following lines in `envvars`:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_NEWVAR=www-newvar
```

when I do this:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${APACHE_RUN_USER}-error.log
```

I get a file called `/var/log/apache2/www-data-error.log` as I'd expect.  But when I do this:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${APACHE_RUN_NEWVAR}-error.log
```

I instead get `/var/log/apache2/${APACHE_RUN_NEWVAR}-error.log`.

I grepped the package source, and `APACHE_LOG_DIR` isn't hardcoded anywhere; it shouldn't be special.  So what's stopping me from using newly created variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not directly replying to the question but according to [passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env), production is the default environment so you shouldn't be needing this line. (I'm guessing you are using passenger)

**Edit:**
I've tried putting `PassEnv APACHE_RUN_NEWVAR` in my vhost config file and it worked. It wasn't working before.

See the [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html) :

> Specifies one or more native system environment variables to make available as internal environment variables

**Edit2:**
Seems like `PassEnv` has nothing to do with it. When I reload the config with `apache2ctl restart` the new variables are not defined but if I do `apache2ctl stop` then `apache2ctl start` it works fine...

Comment: Yeah, but I want to use the same config file in multiple environments on multiple servers.

Comment: Bingo! I have no idea *why* PassEnv is needed for new vars and not for the "standard" vars, but I'll take it..

Comment: But it gets weirder: http://serverfault.com/questions/340355/creating-multiple-variables-in-etc-apache2-envvars

Comment: Thanks again; I never would have thought to try that. Go answer it on the other one and get more acceptance points!