# Creating multiple variables in /etc/apache2/envvars?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I started asking this in [Creating new variables in /etc/apache2/envvars?](https://serverfault.com/questions/340335/creating-new-variables-in-etc-apache2-envvars).  I'm trying to DRY up my Apache config by declaring a few server-specific variables in `/etc/apache2/envvars` and then using them in my `httpd.conf`, but I'm having trouble getting apache to recognize the new variables.

As @ouranos discovered, I can use `PassEnv` to declare new variables.. but only ONE new variable: `RAILS_ENV`.  Watch this:

**/etc/apache2/envvars**:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
export OUR_HOST_NAME='web.production.example.com'
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example**:

```
PassEnv OUR_HOST_NAME RAILS_ENV
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${OUR_HOST_NAME}-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${RAILS_ENV}-access.log combined
```

**ls -1 /var/log/apache2** *-*:

```
${OUR_HOST_NAME}-error.log
production-access.log
```

What? Switching the order of the two variables in `PassEnv` has no effect, either.

Comment: Actually I realised than depending on how apache was restarted the variables were correctly defined. See my second edit on your first question and let me know if it changes anything.

Comment: Don't get thrown off by `PassEnv`, it appears to be a red-herring (See @ouranos's updated comments). I don't use it, and I define multiple variables. I use this strategy on both Ubuntu and RHEL systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said on the [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/340335/creating-new-variables-in-etc-apache2-envvars/) you may have to do `apache2ctl stop && apache2ctl start` as `apache2ctl restart` doesn't seem to read changes in the `envvars` file.